# Ordered fields: Proving that $a<b \Leftrightarrow a^2<b^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

> I need to show that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, 0<a, 0<b:  a<b \Leftrightarrow a^2<b^2$.

---

For $a<b \Rightarrow a^2 < b^2 $ I figured $ a<b $ means that $b=(a+r)$ *(how do I prove this?)* with $r>0$, 
so $$a(a+r) < b^2$$ (multiplicative monotony) 
$$ a^2 + ar <b^2$$ and therefore (by additive monotony and transitivity) the difference $b^2-a^2$ must be positive $$ 0< ar < b^2-a^2$$ since both $a$ and $r$ (and hence their product) $> 0$. From $y-x>0 \Rightarrow y-x+x>0+x \Rightarrow y>x$ it then follows that $a^2<b^2$.

---

For $ a^2 < b^2\Rightarrow a<b $ I have $a^2 + r < b^2$ *(again lacking a proof)* with $r>0$ $$ r<b^2-a^2$$ (by additive monotony)$$0<r<(b+a)(b-a)$$ (binomial formulae were already proved)

I think I now need to prove that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}, 0<ab \Rightarrow $ either $(a,b<0) $or$ (a,b>0)$. My attempt at this would be to show that if for a factor, say $a, 0<a$ holds, it follows that $0<ab \rightarrow (a^{-1})0<(a^{-1})ab \rightarrow 0<b$. For $0>a$ I have $0<ab \rightarrow(a^{-1})0>(a^{-1})ab\rightarrow0>b$. (Inverse and multiplication by a negative factor were already proved.)

Since in the product $(b+a)(b-a)$ the first factor is positive, the second must be too. Hence $a<b$.

I'd like to know

> 1. if my proof is correct and whether there are any gaps in my reasoning and
> 2. if there is a more succinct way to prove it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi! If you have to assume that $a,b\gt 0$, why are you considering the case $a\lt 0$?

Comment: $a,b\in\Bbb R^+$ and $a<b$, then $a^2<ab$ and $a<b$ then $ab<b^2$ so $a^2<b^2$

Comment: As for your question regarding $r$, just set $r = b - a$ and check $r > 0$ as you claim.

Comment: Looks fine to me-I especially like the detail level, some people skip steps,which is a REALLY bad habit.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Thanks for pointing out, I was too fixated that it should also work for a,b < 0 and forgot I don't need to include this case. Though would redundancy be considered a bad style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks good and I don't notice any gaps.

However, for your first proof consider the facts that $a\lt b$, $a=a$, and $b=b$. This gives us $a^2\lt ab$ and $ab\lt b^2$. Transitivity then gives $a^2\lt b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a,b>0$

$a<b \implies a^2<ab$  $-(1)$

$a<b \implies ab<b^2$  $-(2)$

From $(1)\&(2)$ it follows that $a^2<b^2$